# Java : Modifying existing XML create extra ending node while parsing

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

While creating a new node and appending into existing XML-document using below code snippet

the expression is XPath like "rootNode/parentNode1/parentNode2/childNode"

```
  private static Node createParentNode(Document xmlDocument, String expression, String parentRootXPath)
      throws XPathExpressionException {
    final String childXPath = (expression.replace(parentRootXPath, "")).replaceFirst("/", "");
    final StringBuilder parentPathBuilder = new StringBuilder(parentRootXPath);

    Arrays.stream(childXPath.split("/")).forEach(childNodeName -> {
      try {
        Node parentNode = getNode(xmlDocument, parentPathBuilder.toString());
        Node childNode = xmlDocument.createElement(childNodeName);
        parentPathBuilder.append("/").append(childNodeName);
        parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
      } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to create Node {}", parentPathBuilder.toString());
      }
    });

    return getNode(xmlDocument, expression);
  }

  private static Node getNode(Document xmlDocument, String expression) throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (Node) X_PATH.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
  }
```

I am able to append the node but while parsing extra end node tag is generating

```
<DOCUMENT_SETS>
   <DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET>
       <node1>value1</node1>
       <new_Node1>value1</new_Node1>
       <new_Node2>value1</new_Node2>
   </DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT_SETS>
<DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET /> 
<DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET />
```

Input

```
<DOCUMENT_SETS>
   <DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET>
       <node1>value1</node1>
   </DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT_SETS>
```

Expected output

```
<DOCUMENT_SETS>
   <DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET>
       <node1>value1</node1>
       <new_Node1>value1</new_Node1>
       <new_Node2>value1</new_Node2>
   </DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT_SETS>
```

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete sample of input XML, Java code, output you want and the one you get. From your XPath sample `rootNode/parentNode1/parentNode2/childNode` I have no idea how your input looks and I don't see any of the element nodes in the path appearing in the XML sample you have shown.

Comment: Is that XPath `rootNode/parentNode1/parentNode2/childNode` given in the question meant to be applied to the presented input sample? Where do you get the values from?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes like DOCUMENT_SETS/DOCUMENT_SPECIFIC_DATA_SET/new_Node1

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate end tags are get inserted due to creating a child node without checking is the node already exists or not.

```
  private static Node createParentNode(Document xmlDocument, String expression, String parentRootXPath)
      throws XPathExpressionException {
    final String childXPath = (expression.replace(parentRootXPath, "")).replaceFirst("/", "");
    final StringBuilder parentPathBuilder = new StringBuilder(parentRootXPath);

    Arrays.stream(childXPath.split("/")).forEach(childNodeName -> {
      try {
        Node parentNode = getNode(xmlDocument, parentPathBuilder.toString());
        parentPathBuilder.append("/").append(childNodeName);
        Node childNode = getNode(xmlDocument, parentPathBuilder.toString());
        if(Objects.nonNull(childNode)){
           childNode = xmlDocument.createElement(childNodeName);
           parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
        }
      } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to create Node {}", parentPathBuilder.toString());
      }
    });

    return getNode(xmlDocument, expression);
  }
```